# tt files not appearing when creating objects with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am new to Entity Framework, I am able to add the `.edmx` file and then it would autogenerate the objects but I do not see the `.tt` files as shown in the tutorials appearing anywhere this is how it looks

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I do not see anywhere in the code things like `DbSet`, or anything like that.

Would appreciate any help.

```
NOTE : This is database first
```

Comment: What is the .NET Framework version your project is targetting?

Comment: It is targetting the .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Can you show your Edmx file? Is it a new Edmx file or you used a file you already had?

Comment: its a new edmx file, its the first time i work with the framework

Comment: Is it VS2012 RTM or earlier (e.g. RC)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code generation strategy was changed post-RC. VS 2012 Beta and RC versions used code generation strategy that was used in previous versions of Visual Studio. They did not expose T4 templates and generated ObjectContext based contex and EntityObject based entities. Post VS 2012 RC code generation was changed to generate DbContext based context and POCO entities - all using T4 templates. The tutorials are using VS2012 RTM version and therefore you see T4 templates and POCO entities. You either need to use VS2012 RTM (preferred) or EF5 code generator you can get from VS gallery - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da740968-02f9-42a9-9ee4-1a9a06d896a2. The VS gallery page contains links to some blog posts showing how to replace the code generation strategy used by your project.